# MySQL Query to group by date range

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem with this query:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(passDate) as Year,
    count(*) AS total_amount
FROM 
    `dsp_drop_pass_details`
WHERE passDate
    BETWEEN '2009-01-01'
    AND '2012-05-01'
    AND batch='DROPOUT'
GROUP BY YEAR(passDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(passDate)
```

output---

```
Month      total amount
2011             30
2012             20
```

But my desire out put is

```
Month    total amount 
2009           0
2010           0
2011           40
2012           20
```

I want 0 where count is 0

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have a table Years, with all the wanted years.

```
create table Years(yearValue int);

insert into years values (2001), (2002)..., (2020);
```

then do a left join on your actual table.

```
SELECT y.yearValue, COALESCE(COUNT(d.id), 0) --assumning you have a field id in dsp_drop_pass_details
FROM years y
LEFT join dsp_drop_pass_details d on y.yearValue = YEAR(d.passDate)
WHERE y.yearValue between 2009 and 2012
GROUP BY y.yearValue
ORDER BY y.yearValue;
```